# Local DNS wont route users to WPengine blog

Tags: dns, bind9

I'm trying to fix a DNS issue at my office. We run a local Bind server to handle requests to locally run sub domains that are only available in the office. Recently we moved our blog to wpengine.com for hosting. They also provide the ability for DNS control. Basically I need our local DNS to point office users to the wpengine site for our blog subdomain but nothing I do to our local zone file settings makes a difference. Our browsers always get directed to our primary ecom site which originally hosted the blog. I've tried adding sub domain delegation entries to our local zone file to no effect. 
WPengine's settings has a primary DNS config of  blog.fractureme.com   with a CNAME entry of fracture.wpengine.com pointing to blog.fractureme.com . I'm wondering if there's some sort of circular logic going on here with our local office, our primary and Wpengine's DNS that keeps pointing us in the office to the wrong server when we try to go to blog.fractureme.com in a browser?  Our primary domain hosting service also has a CNAME zone entry that points blog.fractureme.com to fracture.wpengine.com .

Meanwhile our office zone file looks like this.
(i did add * to local IP entries. I know thats probably silly trying to balance security with getting the best help). The last entry in the zone file is supposed to be directing blog.fractureme.com to the IP of fracture.wpengine.com.  I've also tried a NS type entry with a 'glue' record with no luck.

```
    ;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA fractureme.com. root.fractureme.com. (
                  2     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  ns1.fractureme.com.
@   IN  NS  dns2.registrar-servers.com.

ns1 IN  A   192.168.1.150
ns2 IN  A   85.25.136.102

fractureme.com. IN  A   64.235.53.182
*   IN  A   64.235.53.182
mobile  IN  A   64.235.53.182
itslog  IN  A   64.235.53.182
blog    IN  CNAME  fracture.wpengine.com
m   IN  CNAME   ghs.google.com.

@   IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx ptr a:fractureme.com a:mail.fractureme.com a:mail1.fractureme.com include:_spf.google.com ~all"
@   IN  MX  10 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@   IN  MX  20 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@   IN  MX  20 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@   IN  MX  30 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@   IN  MX  30 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@   IN  MX  30 ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@   IN  MX  30 ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.


;
; Fracture private addresses
;
prod    IN  A   x.x.x.x
raid    IN  A   x.x.x.x
dev IN  A   64.238.189.200
alex    IN  A   x.x.x.x
caldera IN  A   x.x.x.x
cnc IN  A   x.x.x.x
laser   IN  A   x.x.x.x
encrypted-prod IN   A   x.x.x.x

$ORIGIN prod.staging.fractureme.com.
*   IN  A   64.238.189.199

$ORIGIN itslog.fractureme.com.
*   IN  A   64.235.53.182

$ORIGIN mobile.fractureme.com.
*   IN  A   64.235.53.182

$ORIGIN dev.fractureme.com.
*   IN  A   64.238.189.200

$ORIGIN prod.fractureme.com.
*   IN  A   x.x.x.x
live    IN  A   64.235.53.182

$ORIGIN blog.fractureme.com.
*   IN  A  166.78.99.121
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple suggestions--

Check that you have the correct IP for your site set up in your DNS zone file. There's been some migrations at WPE and this may cause the routing issues.
You can find the updated IP in your my.wpengine.com overview.

If this is a multisite, make sure the domains are added to their user portal as well, one per line with none redirecting to the primary.
Also if multisite, make sure you are using the Wordpress MU domain mapping plugin to direct the domains to the correct subsite rather than trying to do this custom.